# Angular Dynamic Forms - Form with multi part questions do not support validation

Tags: forms, angular, validation

Using the Dynamic Form example provided by Angular (https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) & live example (https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/dynamic-form/eplnkr.html) I am trying to create a dynamic form that has questions with multi part answers.

I have created a live example here (https://plnkr.co/edit/KDG7KCC2Bsi9LLXiIGct?p=preview). The problem I have is that I don't understand how to change the provided validation method to something that will look at the question by its uniquekey and return the correct error. The example method uses this html `<div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{question.label}} is required</div>` and this in the component `isValid() { return this.form.controls[this.question.key].valid; }`

In this example I want to set the maxlength of the fields to 4 but I want to use reactive form validation. Also I would like to use custom validation like setting min and max values for numeric fields. So when the validation is required it correctly shows under the correct field.

This is what my questions-control.service.ts looks like. I think this is where part of the problem lies as the provided validation code does not account for iterating through arrays of answers for one question.

```
questions.forEach(question => {
  for (var key in question.responses) {
    group[question.responses[key].key] = new FormControl(
      question.responses[key].response || ''
    );        
  }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this very easily. Import this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-validation npm package in your project and then add this `import { CustomValidators } from 'ng2-validation';` in your app.module.ts

Then you need to go the questions-control.service.ts and modify this function

```
toFormGroup(questions: QuestionBase<any>[] )
        let group: any = {};
            questions.forEach(question => {
              group[question.key] = question.required ? new FormControl(question.value || '', [Validators.required, CustomValidators.min(10)]): new FormControl(question.value || '');             
            });
            return new FormGroup(group);
          }
```

Comment: I do appreciate the input and I have looked at ng2-validation but I dont think you've actually looked at the example I provided. I have updated my entry to include the example of my questions-control.service.ts

Comment: If you want to create custom validation then you can see this plunk where I have implement the max number validation. https://embed.plnkr.co/7l8HwTVYdlAItgUprAbY/

Comment: That is how I would create validation for the response fields that are in the angular dynamic forms example. But I cannot use that method to apply that validation to my plunk (https://plnkr.co/edit/KDG7KCC2Bsi9LLXiIGct?p=preview) as some of the questions have multiple responses. If you could get this to work on my plunk that would solve my issue.